# Data structure for searching (different) Integers Java

Tags: java, optimization, search, hashmap, standard-library

I am looking for a data structure, optimized for search-operations (in the Java std-lib). I have to iterate over it several times, control every element and delete it in special cases. I have used a HashMap, but I always get following error:

```
for (Edge e : edges) {
    if (special case)
    edges.remove(e);
}

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:810)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:845)
at package.name.TFinder.nN(TFinder.java:83)
at package.name.TFinder.fIT(TFinder.java:56)
at package.name.Main.main(Main.java:215)
```

Comment: You should use Iterator.remove() to avoid this error.

Comment: Do what @Peter said and use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html if you're using multiple threads.

Comment: Iterator.remove()? I Iterate like this: for(Edge e: edges)... and I tried it with edges.remove(e).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, you should be able to use `HashMap` for this. The key is to use `iterator.remove()` to delete entries:

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Key,Value>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
    Map.Entry<Key,Value> entry = it.next();
    // process the entry
    if(need to delete the entry) 
    {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception is thrown when you add/remove(/edit) something in a collection while you're terating through it (in e.g. a for loop).

To solve this, you would use a 'lock' in a multi-threaded environment. If you're doing stuff inside the responsible for-loop itself, you can consider copying your datastructure to a secondary (temporary) one, and then iterate on only one of the two and do all the necessary actions on the other.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually you can use a Copy-On-Write collection to get around locking the collection. As long as modifications to the collection are rare this is quite efficient. But in this case using the iterator is obviously better all along.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: Why? How does this relate to the question?

Comment: He can'y use usual Hashmap but it fits for his needs ? Or i'm not right ?